# Работа с функциями во vue

Tags: vue.js, функции

При входе на страницу запускается функция login (все функции находятся внутри method). После получения положительного  ответа нужно чтобы сработала функция getUser и изменяла значение isAdminings. Но он срабатывает после того как завершается работа функции login.  как можно решить этот вопрос

```
login: function () {
      const user = {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      }
      this.$store.dispatch('Login', user)
        .then((response) => {
          this.getUser(response.data[0])
          console.log('this.isAdminings', this.isAdminings)
          if (this.$route.query.redirect === undefined) {
            this.$router.push('/')
          } else {
            if (this.isAdminings === true) {
              this.$router.push(this.$route.query.redirect || '/')
            } else {
              this.$router.push('/')
            }
          }
          this.isAdminings = false
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.error = err.response.data.detail
        })
    },
    getUser: function (userId) {
      this.$store.dispatch('getUserById', userId)
        .then((response) => {
          this.user = {}
          this.user = response.data
          console.log(this.user.groups)
          if (this.user.groups.includes(1)) {
            this.isAdminings = true
            console.log('this.isAdminings1', this.isAdminings)
          } else {
            this.isAdminings = false
            console.log('this.isAdminings2', this.isAdminings)
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.error = err.response.data.message
        })
    }
```

Comment: vuex логику выносите в соответственную папку и делите на модули

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
this.getUser(response.data[0])
```

поместить в конце функции login